# Is there a Pandas function that can group the hourly data of each day like 2021-01-01 01:00:00 to 2021-01-02 00:00:00 as one group and so on

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've this dataset that contains data observed after each hour of the day. Since the observation is done after every hour, the data starts from 01:00:00 hour and ends at 00:00:00 of the next day.

Is there a way to group these data into a single day starting from hour 01 and ends at hour 00 .

> ```
> 2021-01-01 01:00:00  22.5
> 2021-01-01 02:00:00  25.3
> .
> .
> .
> 2021-01-01 23:00:00  30.2
> 2021-01-02 00:00:00  28.6
>
> 2021-01-02 01:00:00  29.2
> 2021-01-02 02:00:00  30.2
> .
> .
> .
> 2021-01-02 23:00:00  28.2
> 2021-01-03 00:00:00  28.0
> ```

I've tried pd.Grouper but it groups from 00-23 hour.

```
df_Paris['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_Paris['DateTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
davg_df = df_Paris.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='DateTime')).mean()
```

But I need to group data like **day1 01:00:00 - day2 00:00:00**.
Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper column, which is 'DateTime' minus one hour, and use that for grouping.

EX:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ["2020-01-01 01:00", "2020-01-02 00:00",
                                "2020-01-02 01:00", "2020-01-03 00:00"],
                   'value': [1, 1, 3, 3]})

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['helper'] = df['DateTime'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)

davg_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='helper')).mean()
# davg_df
#             value
# helper           
# 2020-01-01      1
# 2020-01-02      3
```